What does 様式美 mean?

Narration: 特に異変は無さそうだから、さっさと確認して終わらせるぞ
Coworker: "左様ですね。しかし、昨日お電話でお話した通り、別件がございまして"
Narration: 聞かなくても分かっているが、一応様式美として問いかけた。
Main character: "別件?"

Context: the character is a wizard working on a job. He needs to check the seal of a monster. The people from his organization are also there and they don't like him.

特に異変は無さそうだから、さっさと確認して終わらせるぞ

here his narration points out that there are no problems so it should be a quick check

"左様ですね。しかし、昨日お電話でお話した通り、別件がございまして"

Then his coworkers that "It's like you say, but as we talked yesterday, there is another issue"

聞かなくても分かっているが、一応様式美として問いかけた。

The character narration that even without asking he know what this is about, but he then asked

"別件?"

May question is what does "様式美として" mean? I'm very stumbled on the meaning of 様式美, From context I take it as " for the sake of appearance"?

In this context, 様式美 likely means "for the sake of form."
While 様式美 generally refers to the "beauty of form." in art, here it implies that following the standard procedure or style is considered good practice, even if it doesn't necessarily make logical sense.
Since they have talked about the another issue (別件) yesterday, the coworker assumes the main character already know about it. However, to adhere to proper form and ensure clarity, the coworker explicitly mentions it again.
